# My car rental program 2 C#?

Tags: c#

I need help with my car program. I am trying to make it so when you click on a car radio button, lets say i wanted a Bugatti, I would click Bugatti radio button and it would calculate the final cost by this code:

```
bugattiDecimal = bugattiFinal * (Decimal)0.20 + rentedDecimal * 25;
```

That code is supposed to calculate 0.20 per mile and $25 per day rented.

This is the rest of the code:

```
//Step 3: Mathmatematical Calculations.
totalMilesDecimal = endingOdometerDecimal - beginningOdometerDecimal;
lamborghiniFinal = endingOdometerDecimal - beginningOdometerDecimal;
ferrariFinal = endingOdometerDecimal - beginningOdometerDecimal;
bugattiFinal = endingOdometerDecimal - beginningOdometerDecimal;
lamborghiniDecimal = lamborghiniFinal * (Decimal)0.12 + rentedDecimal * 15;
ferrariDecimal = ferrariFinal * (Decimal)0.15 + rentedDecimal * 20;
bugattiDecimal = bugattiFinal * (Decimal)0.20 + rentedDecimal * 25;

//This  shows the picture.
if (radLamborghini.Checked) {
   picLamborghini.Visible = true;
   picFerrari.Visible = false;
   picBugatti.Visible = false;
}

if (radLamborghini.Checked) {
   lblFinalCost.Text = lamborghiniDecimal.ToString();
}

private void radFerrari_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //This shows the picture.
   if (radFerrari.Checked) {
      picFerrari.Visible = true;
      picLamborghini.Visible = false;
      picBugatti.Visible = false;
   }

   if (radFerrari.Checked) {
      lblFinalCost.Text = ferrariDecimal.ToString();
   }
}

private void radBugatti_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //This shows the picture.
   if (radBugatti.Checked) {
      picBugatti.Visible = true;
      picLamborghini.Visible = false;
      picFerrari.Visible = false;
   }

   if (radBugatti.Checked) {
      lblFinalCost.Text = bugattiDecimal.ToString();
   }
}
```

Is my code right? When I click one of the radio buttons, they all calculate tjhe same cost.

Comment: I suggest setting breakpoints on the two places you set `lblFinalCost.Text`. Ensure they are being called and check the value in the `____Decimal` variables to ensure they're what you expected. You set a breakpoint on a line in Visual Studio by pressing `F9` in case you don't know.

Comment: Do the pictures change?

Comment: Does it seem to always be calculating the Lamborghini?

Comment: I really think you should post all of your code.  How are you setting your decimals, for instance?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @JLott yes it is always calculating lamborghini.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code for your lamborghini bit isn't in an event handler. That could cause that code to always fire and if your other radio buttons aren't wired to their respective events, the lamborghini code will always run and the code for the other cars won't ever run.